# Using FeedMe with the instagram API

Tags: json, feed, plugin-feedme

Just downloaded FeedMe, and it seems like a great solution to what I want to do, but I can't get it to succesfully run a json import on a feed generated by instagram. When I hit 'Save and Continue', I get a PHP warning:

```
file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

It's on this line:

```
 public function getRawData($url)
     {
     if (file_get_contents(__FILE__) && ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
         $content = file_get_contents($url);
     } else if (function_exists('curl_version')) {
         $curl = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         $content = curl_exec($curl);
         curl_close($curl);
     }

     return ($content) ? $content : false;
 }
```

It's worth noting, I have no idea what to set the Primary Element as. Didn't see any documentation for JSON on the readme

Comment: You may not necessarily need to set the primary element for JSON feeds, it's more for XML feeds where there must be a root node. It's not explained very well I'll agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a server (DNS) configuration issue. PHP can't open the URL because it can't resolve the domain.

Comment: Good call. I tested this out in staging, and everything went through. Definitely something going on with my local install. Thanks!